# Reverted when adding another logic in Uniswap swap functions

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, defi, swaps

I have been learning how to use Uniswap V2 recently and am trying to add logic on top of the original code. I want to have a fee of 1% on each swap transaction using the input token. I was successfully implemented the code for exact input (e.g., swap exact tokens for tokens), but I am struggling to implement the code for exact output (e.g., swap tokens for exact tokens), because the error that was shown is only `execution reverted` from the remix IDE. Here is a snippet of my code.

**note: you have to have some amount of the input token in this smart contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
import '@uniswap/lib/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
/* 
Goerli network:
WETH: 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6
*/ 

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

interface IWETH {
    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint) external;

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

interface ISwapV2Router {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    //token exact amount in, token -> token 1
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    //token exact amount out, token -> token 2
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    //ETH exact amount in, exact ETH -> token 3
    function swapExactETHForTokens
    (uint amountOutMin, 
    address[] calldata path, 
    address to, 
    uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    //ETH exact amount out, token -> exact ETH 4
    function swapTokensForExactETH(
        uint amountOut, 
        uint amountInMax, 
        address[] calldata path, 
        address to, 
        uint deadline
        ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);


    // token exact amount in, exact token -> ETH 5
    function swapExactTokensForETH(
        uint amountIn, 
        uint amountOutMin, 
        address[] calldata path, 
        address to, 
        uint deadline
        )
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    // token exact amout out, ETH -> exact token 6
    function swapETHForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut, 
        address[] calldata path, 
        address to, 
        uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;

    // calculate maximum output token, useful for exact token -> token
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    // calculate minimum input token, useful for token -> exact token
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

contract SwapCentral {
    address public owner;
    address payable public dev;
    uint    public exchangeFee = 1000; //1% = 0.01 = 1000/denomFee
    uint    public constant DENOM_FEE = 1e5;

    address public immutable WETH;
    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;

    ISwapV2Router private constant V2_ROUTER = ISwapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER);

    mapping (address => bool) public isExcludedFromFee;
    
    constructor(address _WETH){
        require(_WETH != address(0), "WETH can't be address zero");
        WETH = _WETH;
        owner = msg.sender;
        isExcludedFromFee[msg.sender] = true;
        dev = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner, "you're not the owner");
        _;
    }

    //---------------Uniswap V2 Starts Here----------------------//
    function v2GetEstimatedIn(uint amountOutDesired, address tokenIn, address tokenOut) public view returns (uint){
        address[] memory path = createPath(tokenIn, tokenOut);
        uint[] memory amount = V2_ROUTER.getAmountsIn(amountOutDesired, path);
        return amount[0];
    }

    //1. token exact amount in, exact token -> token 
    function v2SwapExactTokensForTokens(
        address caller,
        address tokenIn, 
        address tokenOut, 
        uint amountIn, 
        uint amountOutMin,
        uint deadlineInSeconds
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)
    {
        uint[] memory dividedAmount = splitTokenValue(msg.sender, amountIn); //split the token

        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenIn, msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(tokenIn, UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, dividedAmount[1]);
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(tokenIn, dev, dividedAmount[0]); //transfer to developer

        address[] memory path = createPath(tokenIn, tokenOut);
        amounts = V2_ROUTER.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            dividedAmount[1],
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            caller,
            block.timestamp + deadlineInSeconds
        );
    }

    //2. token exact amount out, token -> exact token
    function v2SwapTokensForExactTokens(
        address caller,
        address tokenIn,
        address tokenOut,
        uint amountOutDesired,
        uint amountInMax,
        uint deadlineInSeconds
    ) public returns (uint[] memory amounts, bool success) 
    {
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenIn, msg.sender, address(this), amountInMax);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(tokenIn, UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, amountInMax); //approval for swapping
        
        uint estAmountIn = v2GetEstimatedIn(amountOutDesired, tokenIn, tokenOut); //calculate estimation
        uint[] memory dividedAmount = splitTokenValue(msg.sender, amountInMax); //split the token
        require((estAmountIn + dividedAmount[0] <= amountInMax), "amountInMax is not sufficient");

        // swapping with the amount of amountToSwap 
        address[] memory path = createPath(tokenIn, tokenOut);
        amounts = V2_ROUTER.swapTokensForExactTokens(
            amountOutDesired,
            dividedAmount[1],
            path,
            caller,
            block.timestamp + deadlineInSeconds
        );

        //transfer to dev
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(tokenIn, dev, dividedAmount[0]); 
        
        // refund the change to caller
        if(amounts[0] < amountInMax){
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(tokenIn, UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, 0);
            TransferHelper.safeTransfer(tokenIn, msg.sender, amountInMax - amounts[0] - dividedAmount[0]);
        }
        success = true;
    }

    //---------------Helper Functions----------------------//
    function splitTokenValue(address userAddress, uint amount) private view returns (uint[] memory dividedValue){
        uint fee;
        isExcludedFromFee[userAddress] ? fee = 0: fee = exchangeFee;

        dividedValue[0] = (amount * fee) / DENOM_FEE; //amountToDev
        dividedValue[1] = amount - dividedValue[0]; //amountToSwap
        require(amount >= dividedValue[1], "calculation error");
    }

    function createPath(address tokenIn, address tokenOut) private pure returns (address[] memory){
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenIn; //input token
        path[1] = tokenOut; //output token
        return path;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

Is there anything I missed? Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you very much!

Comment: It will be easier if you can share a failed transaction (by forcing it on chain) or at least the hex data from the transaction so we can simulate it. Just auditing a wall of code without access to accounts approvals, balances and exact inputs is I think not inviting for people.

Comment: @Maka thank you for your response. I agree that I should have the failed transaction. However I already solved this error. It turned out I couldn't use the logic for dividing the token just like for exactInput and had to make another function to do that

Comment: glad you got it sorted, well done.